# Error using AutoComplete of Material UI + react hook form

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui, react-hook-form

I am using the component 'AutoComplete' of material Ui to render multiple Checkboxes, and show the options selected into a TextField.
The error occurs when I submit the form. The values of checkboxes selected are empty, like this: category: ""
It seems the react hook form is not recognizing the name "category", like below:

```
 <Autocomplete
    id="checkboxes-tags-demo"
    fullWidth
    multiple
    limitTags={2}
    getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
    disableCloseOnSelect
    noOptionsText="Nenhuma opção foi encontrada"
    variant="outlined"
    options={newCategories}
    renderOption={(option, {selected}) => {
      return (
        <Box key={option.id} ml={option?.isSub ? 3 : 0}>
           <Checkbox
              icon={icon}
              checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
              checked={selected}
            />
            {option.title}
        </Box>
       )
     }
    }
    renderInput={(params) =>
      <TextField
        name="category"
        inputRef={register}
        {...params}
        label="Selecione a categoria"
        variant="outlined" />}
      />
    }
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the Material UI `Autocomplete` with the `Controller` Component provided by React Hook Form. See this [section](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#IntegratingwithUIlibraries) in the documentation for further information.

[image: Edit React Hook Form - MUI Autocomplete]

Comment: thanks!! it works fine on codeSandbox, but when I use in my project, I get undefined on "value", when:  render={({ field: { value, onChange } }). Do you think could be my version of React Hook form? im using currently: "react-hook-form": "^6.15.3",

Comment: Yes, sorry. I used the recent version v7 for the CodeSandbox. With this new version the signature of the `render` prop function changed. For v6 it would be: `render={({ value, onChange }) => ... }`.

Comment: hey! if You could help a little bit more, im trying to do this since yesterday. Now im using the same component, but now to edit data.  I have to set default checked values.  At first, it seems to work fine, but if you click a checked button doest work as expected. Here the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/embed/dazzling-jones-u4dyg?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: `Autocomplete` uses strict equality by default to determine if an option is selected. As your `defaultCategory` objects don't have the same reference as `newCategories`, the check will fail. You have to use the `getOptionSelected` prop to find the correct and corresponding object from  `newCategories` for all your `defaultCategory` objects. Check the [docs](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/) for more info.  Here is the updated [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rhf-mui-autocomplete--equalbyid-eb3z5?file=/src/App.js).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct way to set up the autocomplete for multiple values:

- `multiple` to add multiple values,
- `options`: you add the options to be selected
- `getOptionLabel`: to show up the label of the options
- `onChange`: use onChange function of `react-hook-form` to set the selected values
- `renderInput`: to render the input

```js
import { useForm, Controller } from 'react-hook-form'
import {
  Box,
  TextField,
  Autocomplete,
} from '@mui/material'

const {
  ...
  control,
  formState: { errors },
} = useForm()

<Box mt={2}>
  <Controller
    control={control}
    name="industries"
    rules={{
      required: 'Veuillez choisir une réponse',
    }}
    render={({ field: { onChange } }) => (
      <Autocomplete
        defaultValue={
          useCasesData?.industries
            ? JSON.parse(useCasesData?.industries)
            : []
        }
        multiple
        disableCloseOnSelect
        options={companyIndustryTypes}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
        onChange={(event, values) => {
          onChange(values)
        }}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            label="Type d'industries"
            placeholder="Type d'industries"
            helperText={errors.industries?.message}
            error={!!errors.industries}
          />
        )}
      />
    )}
  />
</Box>
```

> Note that options in my case `companyIndustryTypes` is an array of object :

```json
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Accounting",
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Administration & Office Support",
    },
    ...
]
```

[image]